# How to determine if collection containing more than one max result?

Tags: java, collections

```
List<Integer> list;
java.util.Collections.max(list)
```

How can I determine if the list contains more than one max result? So to say: if I found the maximum, how can I ensure that this is the only entry in a collection?

Thanks

Comment: You mean, it doesn't have duplicates?

Comment: Could you give some context please ? Depending on your needs a Set might or not be more suitable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Integer max = Collections.max(list);
boolean containsMultipleMax = (list.indexOf(max) != list.lastIndexOf(max));
```

Comment: This is producing a boolean from the first found max and the last found. Correct ?

Comment: @JamesPoulson: yep, that's what it does.

Comment: It looks where the max is in the list, starting from the beginning of the list. It looks where the max is in the list, starting from the end of the list. If the two found indices don't match, then the max is at least twice in the list. If they match, the max is only once in the list.

Answer (score 2):

I'd avoid using Collections.max().  Just write your own method.  Otherwise, you traverse the collection twice: once for max(), which has to 'see' all elements, and second time form indexOf() + lastIndexOf().

```
boolean containsMultipleMax;
Iterator<Integer> i = list.iterator();
Integer max = i.next();

while (i.hasNext()) {
    Integer next = i.next();
    final int cmp = next.compareTo(max);
    if (cmp > 0) {
        max = next;
        containsMultipleMax = false;
    } else if (cmp == 0) {
        containsMultipleMax = true;
    }
}
```

Obviously, it depends on the size of your collection... If it's below 1M, just ignore me ;).